# Converting elliptic curve equations

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm implementing a digital signature algorithm for academic purposes using elliptic curves. I am familiar with equations of the form $$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$$, but the paper I am reading for implementing point addition and doubling uses the equation $$Y^2Z = X^3 +aXZ^2 +bZ^3$$.

I guess the $Z$ comes from representing the points using projective coordinates, but I'm not sure.

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I think I can rewrite one equation as the other. Can someone explain the process of converting an equation of the form $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ to the equation $Y^2Z = X^3 +aXZ^2 +bZ^3$?

I appreciate any guidance on this matter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [In Standard Projective Coordinates the triple (X, Y, Z) represents the affine point (X / Z, Y / Z)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Standard_Projective_Coordinates)

Comment: If you just want to understanding transforming the equation, then the  process is just (1) look at the highest degree monomial that appears (in this case, $X^3$), and then *homogenise* the equation by multiplying each monomial $X^iY^j$ by an extra monomial $Z^k$ such that $i+j+k=3$ is the highest degree you found. So here $X \to XZ^2$, $Y^2\to Y^2Z$, etc. Then now every term is of degree 3: $Y^2Z, X^3,XZ^2,Z^3$. And moreover, as you noted, it's in projective coordinates now, meaning if you map $(X:Y:Z)\to(\alpha X:\alpha Y:\alpha Z)$, the equation still holds. This helps with $\infty=(0:1:0)$

Answer (score 2):

> Explain the process of converting an equation of the form $y^2=x^3+a\,x+b$ to the equation $Y^2\,Z=X^3+a\,X\,Z^2+b\,Z^3$

This is projective coordinates. The idea is to express $x$ and $y$ as ratios $\frac XZ$ and $\frac YZ$ (with $x$, $y$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ all in the base field). This has the beneficial effect that during point multiplication, we can defer to the end the expensive step of modular inversion that occurs for each point addition and doubling when we use Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$.

Starting from from $y^2=x^3+a\,x+b$, changing $x$ to $\frac XZ$ and $y$ to $\frac YZ$ yields $\frac{Y^2}{Z^2}=\frac{X^3}{Z^3}+a\frac XZ+b$. And then multiplying by $Z^3$ yields $Y^2\,Z=X^3+a\,X\,Z^2+b\,Z^3$.

To obtain explicit point addition and doubling formulas, we can transform the [standard formulas](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1) by making the same change of variable. There are many ways to arrange the computations, see the [Explicit-Formulas Database](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-projective.html).

To convert from $(x,y)$ to $(X,Y,Z)$, set $X=x$, $Y=y$, and $Z=1$.

To convert from $(X,Y,Z)$ to $(x,y)$ when $Z\ne0$, compute the inverse $Z^{-1}$ of $Z$, then set $x={Z^{-1}}X$ and $y={Z^{-1}}y$.

Note: We can initially represent the neutral/point at infinity $\mathcal O$ as $(X,Y,Z)=(0,1,0)$, and these formulas yield correct results, including when $\mathcal O$ is obtained as an intermediary value. At the end of a sequence of operations, we can convert back $(X,Y,Z)$ to $\mathcal O$ when $Z=0$.

Comment: Another popular option for fast point multiplication with deferred modular inversion is [Jacobian coordinates](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-jacobian-0.html), which express $x$ and $y$ as ratios $\frac X{Z^2}$ and $\frac Y{Z^3}$.